Count button clicks on custom post type cards and order them by button clicks in Wordpress
in Wordpress, I have created a custom post type to display as a list of cards. Inside this post type, I have created a custom field that displays button with a link to an outside website. I would like to display these post types cards by order of how many times their buttons have been clicked thus popular cards coming on top. Is it at all possible?
Thanks a lot in advance!
I can order my post type cards by meta key value and meta key value number so maybe there is a way to utilize that? But I have no idea how to hook into those...
